# How to create multidimensional array in angular2 with object data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, multidimensional-array, angular

I have array object, but i want to create its array: 
Object format like as:

```
[
 {"name":"A1","type":"type1"},
 {"name":"A2","type":"type1"},
 {"name":"A3","type":"type1"},
 {"name":"A4","type":"type1"},
 {"name":"B1","type":"type2"},
 {"name":"C1","type":"type3"},
 {"name":"D1","type":"type4"},
 {"name":"D2","type":"type4"}
]
```

Result format like  :

```
["type1"=>[A1,A2,A3,A4],"type2"=>[B1],"type3"=>[C1],"type3"=>[D1,D2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the array with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and use an object with the type as keys.

```js
var data = [{ "name": "A1", "type": "type1" }, { "name": "A2", "type": "type1" }, { "name": "A3", "type": "type1" }, { "name": "A4", "type": "type1" }, { "name": "B1", "type": "type2" }, { "name": "C1", "type": "type3" }, { "name": "D1", "type": "type4" }, { "name": "D2", "type": "type4" }],
    grouped = {};

data.forEach(function (a) {
    grouped[a.type] = grouped[a.type] || [];
    grouped[a.type].push(a.name);
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  if (prev.hasOwnProperty(cur.type))
    prev[cur.type].push(cur.name);
  else
    prev[cur.type] = [cur.name];

  return prev;
}, {});
```

The nice thing about this approach is there is no need for extra variables out of the scope of the reduce, it simply returns your grouped object.

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLm00zt7/)